# Object Expected - Javascript/Jquery IE8 Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this questions has been asked alot and I checked few of them but none worked for me.

I have a drop down menu using simple Jquery functions. It works perfectly fine in all other brothers , but I get "Object Expected Error" in IE8 and lower.

Here is my JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

 $(function() {
 $('#CLink').on('mouseover', function() {
        $('.CContent').fadeIn('slow');
        ('.PContent').fadeOut('slow');
        return false;
    });
    $('#nav-wrapper').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.CContent').fadeOut('slow');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Tried to place my Jquery at header of the site, still no effect.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried using jquery-migrate?

Comment: Hi @JohnC. I just added jquery-migrate and didn't solve anything.  I will include this in my original question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery 2.0` (and above) **do not** support Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 ([read more](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)).

Anyway, you can use `jQuery 1.x` or [jQuery migrate plugin.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)

Comment: Thanks. I Used JQuery migrate, but didn't solve it , but changing JQuery 2.x to 1.x solved this issue. Thanks alot.